# How to delete a cookie for real?

Tags: javascript, php

I've managed to mangle my cookie string in IE so badly, it now looks like this:

```
"; __atuvc=4%7C7; PHPSESSID=e4db10eb5d4409ba3203a7c1d533fafd; PHPSESSID=75a04bdcf604dd607d383da774c0f72a; __utmc=51433896; __utma=51433896.100703801.1392175783.1392175783.1392178863.2; __utmb=51433896.5.10.1392178863; __utmz=51433896.1392175783.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __atuvc=3%7C7"
```

That's the output of typing `document.cookie` into the IE11 developer bar.

You will notice `PHPSESSID` is in there twice. I want to kill it.

I've tried running this in JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

And running this in PHP:

```
session_start();
setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-3600); 
setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-3600, '/'); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

But nothing seems to get rid of the cookie.

I'm aware I can delete the cookies manually through the browser, but a whole bunch of users have fried sessions right now, and I need a way to do it automatically.

Comment: What you have if var_dump($_COOKIE)?

Comment: `var_dump($_COOKIE)` will only output the `PHPSESSID` once because it's a key-value dict. But it's definitely in there twice, because it prevents users from logging in. It can also be seen via `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`.

Comment: So far the only solution I've found is to ask the user to close their browser (will clear session-length cookies) or press Ctrl+Shift+Del and delete them manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a cookie you must specify cookie params exactly like when it were set. You can use `session_get_cookie_params` function to get current session cookie's params

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(
    session_name(), '', time() - 86400, 
    $params['path'], 
    $params['domain'],
    $params['secure'],
    $params['httponly']
);

session_destroy();
```